# CellFactory vs CellValueFactory

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx-8, fxml

Let me sketch the situation.

I have a class with an integer variable and I have a TableView with 3 columns '< 100', '100-200' and '> 200' where `MyClass` objects are added. Depending on the `myIntValue` of the object, a **x** is shown in the correct column. Now I wonder what the best approach is to get this result.

**First option**, make methods in `MyClass`and use those as my the `CellValueFactory` for my columns:

```
public class MyClass{
   ...
   private int myIntValue;
   ...

   public boolean getLessThan100(){
       return myIntValue < 100;        
   }
   public boolean getBetween100And200(){
       return myIntValue >= 100 && myIntValue <= 200;        
   }
   public boolean getMoreThan200(){
       return myIntValue > 200;        
   }
}
```

And in my controller:

```
tcLessThan100.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<MyClass, Boolean>("lessThan100"));
tcBetween100And200.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<MyClass, Boolean>("between100And200"));
tcMoreThan200.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<MyClass, Boolean>("moreThan200"));
```

**Second option**, don't make extra methods in `MyClass`and use `CellFactory` instead:

```
public class MyClass{
   ...
   private int myIntValue;
   ...

   public int getMyIntValue(){
       return myIntValue;        
   }
}
```

And in my controller:

```
tcLessThan100.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<MyClass, Integer>("myIntValue"));
tcLessThan100.setCellFactory(CustomCellFactories.getXCellFactory100());
tcBetween100And200.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<MyClass, Integer>("myIntValue"));
tcBetween100And200.setCellFactory(...);
tcMoreThan200.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<MyClass, Integer>("myIntValue"));
tcMoreThan200.setCellFactory(...);
```

In the CustomCellFactories class:

```
public static Callback<TableColumn<MyClass, Integer>, TableCell<MyClass, Integer>> getXCellFactory100() {
    return new Callback<TableColumn<MyClass, Integer>, TableCell<MyClass, Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public TableCell<MyClass, Integer> call(TableColumn<MyClass, Integer> param) {
            TableCell<MyClass, Integer> cell = new TableCell<MyClass, Integer>() {
                @Override
                public void updateItem(final Integer item, final boolean empty) {
                    if (empty) {
                        setText(null);
                        setGraphic(null);
                    } else {
                        Label label = new Label();

                        if (item < 100) {
                            label.setText("x");
                        }
                        setGraphic(label);
                    }

                }
            };
            cell.setEditable(false);
            cell.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            return cell;
        }
    };
}
```

I was able to get both options to work, but I wonder if one of the options is the better way to do it (e.g. for better performance, ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answer: There's very little computation going on here. So, both in terms of memory and CPU performance, it does not matter if you do it one way or the other. Any difference is negligible, in comparison to everything else going on when displaying a `TableView`.

So, in my opinion, this is purely a design issue. What are the more important features/properties of `MyClass` from a domain perspective? Is it `myIntValue` or is it the three categories `myIntValue` can fit into?`

Based on my understanding of the problem right now, I'd choose option two, as I see the less-than/between/greater-than more as a visualization detail, rather than an important domain aspect. But you may choose to do it otherwise, without there being anything wrong with that. :-)